# rapidminer some concepts

Tags: rapidminer

In rapidminer what is the meaning of:

```
    - training cycles
    - learning rate
    - momentum
```

I'm trying to work with rapidminer but i cant understand this notions. Any help would be apreciated, as newbly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is terminology used in neural nets (and the libraries RapidMiner is using, resp.) , not RapidMiner in particular.

Here is a really short explanation. For more details you have to study neural networks.

A Multi-Layer Perceptron with Backpropagation learns the model (i.e. adjusts the weights/backpropagates the error) in several iteration which are called **training cycle**. In each iteration the error will be reduced.

The **learning rate** specifies how much the old weight contributes to the learning in each cycle. A too large rate leads to a bad flexibility of the model and it can yield a local minima. A too small value means that the model will be learnt very slowly. Use a small value and increase it carefully if your learning is to slow.

The **momentum** is another parameter which determines if you get stuck in a local minima (small value) or not (large value, but with a unstable learning).